# Upgrading from Lotus Domino 8.5.1 to 8.5.2 - need help badly

Tags: ibm-domino

We are trying to upgrade a development server from Lotus Domino 8.5.1 to 8.5.2.  I have tried this several ways and every time I do it after it is done it can no longer find the server.  Our development setup is such that we have a replication server (Domino 6.5) and each server is installed as a standalone that hits the replication.   I have tried

- Uninstalling 8.5.1 and installing 8.5.2. I left the data directory intact and used the same
  server.id file
- Just installing 8.5.2 over 8.5.1
- Wiping the entire 8.5.1, including the data directory and local ID file and installing 8.5.2

Every time I get the error:

```
Unable to find patch to server. Check that your network connection is working.  
If you have a working connection, go to Preferences - Notes Ports and click 
Trace to discover where it breaks down.
```

Here is the trace:

**TCP/IP**

```
Determining path to server DomBlackBerry/domain 
Available Ports:  TCPIP LAN0
Checking normal priority connection documents only...
Allowing wild card connection documents...
Enabling name service requests and probes...
Checking for DomBlackBerry/domain on TCPIP using address 'DomBlackBerry'
Unable to connect to DomBlackBerry/domain on TCPIP (The server is not responding. The server may be down or you may be experiencing network problems. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.)
Checking for DomBlackBerry/domain on LAN0 using address 'DomBlackBerry'
Unable to connect to DomBlackBerry/domain on LAN0 (Remote system not responding)
Checking low and normal priority connection documents...
No default passthru server defined
Unable to find any path to DomBlackBerry/domain because
Unable to find path to server. Check that your network connection is working. If you have a working connection, go to Preferences - Notes Ports and click Trace to discover where it breaks down.
```

**LAN0**

```
Determining path to server DomBlackBerry/domain 
Available Ports:  TCPIP LAN0
Checking normal priority connection documents only...
Allowing wild card connection documents...
Enabling name service requests and probes...
Checking for DomBlackBerry/domain on TCPIP using address 'DomBlackBerry'
Unable to connect to DomBlackBerry/domain on TCPIP (The server is not responding. The server may be down or you may be experiencing network problems. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.)
Checking for DomBlackBerry/domain on LAN0 using address 'DomBlackBerry'
Unable to connect to DomBlackBerry/domain on LAN0 (Remote system not responding)
Checking low and normal priority connection documents...
No default passthru server defined
Unable to find any path to DomBlackBerry/domain because 
Unable to find path to server. Check that your network connection is working. If you have a working connection, go to Preferences - Notes Ports and click Trace to discover where it breaks down.
```

I also have BES 4.1.3.4 installed on this.  It all works fine in 8.5.1.  Can anyone point me in any kind of right direction of what to do?  Admittedly I am not a server admin but, the person who used to do this is no longer here so I have to figure it out.

Comment: Actually, I may have just solved this.  If I turn on driver errors in the trace I get the following: DNS returned address [wrong IP here] for DomBlackberry.  The server was moved to a new location with a new IP and it looks like the DNS needs to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer, in case anyone in the future needs it.

If I turn on driver errors in the trace I get the following: DNS returned address

```
[wrong IP here] for DomBlackberry.
```

The server was moved to a new location with a new IP and it looks like the DNS needs to updat